# How to render another page onclick

Tags: reactjs

I'm using Reactjs. I want to render another page on the same place where main page is render. Below is code for my `app.js` file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Online from './components/userview';
import Login from './components/login';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    this.state = { LoggedIn: false };
  }
  handleLogin(props) {
    this.setState = { LoggedIn: true };
    console.log(this.setstate.LoggedIn);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="header col-lg-12">
          <img
            src={require('../src/images/logo.png')}
            style={{ maxWidth: '80vh', maxHeight: '100vh' }}
          />
        </div>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={this.handleLogin}
        >
          Sign In
        </button>&nbsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
          Join Live chat
        </button>
        <Login />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and here is the page which I want to render at the place to `app.js`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login">
        <form>
          <div>
            <label>Your ID:</label>
            <input type="text" ref="id" />
          </div>
          <br />

          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How to render this page when I click on login button?

Comment: Sorry what's your question?

Comment: when ma application starts it gives me to buutons login and join group.. i want when i click on login it gives me a form and ma start page is hide by somehow..

Comment: Sounds like you need routing. React router https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router will give you the ability to render a new 'page' when a button / link is clicked

Answer (score 0):

In your App render method, you can do :

```
if(this.state.LoggedIn) return <Login />
```

Comment: render() {
   
   if(this.state.LoggedIn)
   {
     return <Login/>
   }
     
    
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <div className="header col-lg-12">
        <img src={require("../src/images/logo.png")} style={{maxWidth:'80vh',maxHeight:'100vh'}}/> 
        </div>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleLogin}>Sign In</button>&nbsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Join Live chat</button> 
       
      </div>
     
    ); like this ???

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code inside the `App` component's `render` method.

```
render(){
    if(this.state.LoggedIn)
        return <Login />;
    else {
        return(
            <div className="App">
                ....
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Check the working code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mmpz85kqlx)

Comment: @AhmadBilal check the working code on CodeSandbox. If you want to change the state, change it this way -> `this.setState({key:"someValue"});` not like you were doing.